# Can't override user agent stylesheet rules even via style attribute?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm using `Ublock Origin` browser extension that hides ads by injecting css rules into `user agent stylesheet`:

```
a[href^="https://ad.doubleclick.net/"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

It hides the link even with style attribute:

```html
there should be a link:
<a href="https://ad.doubleclick.net/" style="display: block !important">example1</a>
```

Even though devtools shows the style attribute should be overriding that rule:
[image]

The computed style seems to disagree (the link remains hidden):
[image]

A similar css rule in "user stylesheet" can be overwritten by style attribute no problem:

```css
a[href^="https://example.net/"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
there should be a link:
<a href="https://example.net/" style="display: block !important">example2</a>
```

Is this a browser bug?
Is there a work around this?

```
Edge 119.0.2151.44
Windows 10 x64
```

Comment: I imagine Ublock Origin has measures in place to prevent this sort of thing, after all, it wouldn't be much of an adblocker if you could just add an inline style to all your ads.

Comment: @DBS good point. It's just first time I see that there is a higher authority over style attribute...

Comment: Appears to follow the hierarchy that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order outlines. "author (developer) !important" has prio 5, so that is two lower than "user-agent (browser) !important", which has the second-highest prio there is. So, not a browser bug IMHO, but - works as designed.

Comment: @CBroe I think the bug here is in the dev-tools rather than the rendered HTML, perhaps I'm reading it wrong, but it looks (in the first screenshot) like the dev-tools are interpreting the priorities incorrectly?

Comment: @CBroe I think your comment is worth an answer ;)

Comment: @DBS you are correct, devtools is confused, seems like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behavior appears to follow the hierarchy that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order outlines.

The origin "author (developer)" with importance `!important` comes at position 5 in the (ascending) order in which these things take priority, whereas "user-agent (browser)" with `!important` is at position 7, and therefor overrules the author stylesheet.

So the interpretation by the browser appears to be correct here; and the bug would be on the dev tools side, which do not "visualize" this correctly.